# Dynamic programming problem for minimum cost

Tags: algorithm

I have a cell tower question. There are n towns. We want to build cell tower in some of the towns. Each cell tower can cover itself and its neighbor. Each town has a cost to build cell tower. We want to find out the minimum cost to build the cell tower to cover all towns.

For example,

(1)

### TOWN 1 2 3

COST 5 1 2
We select to build cell tower in town-2. The cost is 1.

(2)

### TOWN 1 2 3 4

COST 5 1 2 3
We select to build cell tower in town-2/3. The cost is 1+2=3.

(3)

### TOWN 1 2 3 4

COST 5 1 3 2

We select to build cell tower in town-2/4. The cost is 1+2=3.

It's a dynamic programming algorithm. How can I solve it?

Thanks
Ling

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: think about couple of hours. no idea till now ...:(

Comment: If this is for Stanford's CS161 course, please be sure to cite that you asked for the answer on Stack Overflow!

Comment: What did you think about that didn't work? Maybe something you thought about wasn't that far off and just needed a little polishing. EDIT: I guess you won't be answering this question then, templatetypedef? :P

Comment: @G.Bach: Seems like the problem I assigned here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs161/handouts/130%20Problem%20Set%206.pdf#page=2 .  So yeah, I probably won't be answering this. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef that made my day

Comment: @templatetypedef I thought this is something you might get up to. Do you guys post solutions after the deadline? I'd be curious to see whether you do something more elegant than what I thought of.

Comment: @G.Bach- Yep!  I'll post it on Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something among the following lines:

```
f(0,_) = 0
f(1,true) = 0
f(1,false) = cost[1]
f(x,true) = min{ f(x-1,true) + cost[x], f(x-1,false) }
f(x,false) = min { f(x-1,true) + cost[x], f(x-2,true) + cost[x-1]}
```

The idea is:

`x` is the current number of city we are looking at, and the boolean is true if this city is already covered (by the city from the left).

- `f(0,_)` is an empty base clause - it is free to cover nothing.
- `f(1,false)` is base where city 1 is not covered, so you must put a tower there, and `f(1,true)` is a base where city 1 is covered, so you don't need a tower and you are done.
- `f(x,true)` is the case that the city x is already covered, so you can put there a tower, and continue to the next city [which is also covered - `f(x-1,true)`], or don't put a tower there, and the next city is not covered [`f(x-1,false)`]
- `f(x,false)` is the case where city x is not covered, so you basically have two choices, or put a tower in there, and then continue to `f(x-1,true)`. Or put a tower in the next city (in x-1) and then continue to `f(x-2,true)`

Start with `f(x,false)`, where `x` is the last city, and you'll get the minimal solution. 

It is easy to see that this recursive formula can easily be modified to DP.