# minimum cost using dynammic programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have a cell tower question. There are n towns. We want to build cell tower in some of the towns. Each cell tower can cover itself and its neighbor. Each town has a cost to build cell tower. We want to find out the minimum cost to build the cell tower to cover all towns.

For example,

(1)

TOWN 1 2 3

COST 5 1 2 We select to build cell tower in town-2. The cost is 1.

(2)

TOWN 1 2 3 4

COST 5 1 2 3 We select to build cell tower in town-2/3. The cost is 1+2=3.

(3)

TOWN 1 2 3 4

COST 5 1 3 2

We select to build cell tower in town-2/4. The cost is 1+2=3.
 Is there a way to solve this problem in O(n) time? i looked at the post on [dynamic programming proboem for minimum cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157141/dynamic-programming-proboem-for-minimum-cost) but i think the answer given there is O(n^2). I thought about the LIS in dynamic programming but i think it will run in O(n^2) as well.

Comment: Why do you think that the answer there is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic programming proboem for minimum cost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157141/dynamic-programming-proboem-for-minimum-cost)

Comment: @ btilly, actually  you are right, it is O(n). Is there a way to express or  convert  and  code this using Dynamic Programming?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is way to solve this problem in O(n). The answer given in the post has linear time complexity so its just what you need.

Comment: i think think you are right. Is there a way to express or convert and code this using Dynamic Programming? sorry i am new to these techniques

Comment: @masheranosanchez Yes. You can store the values in a 2-d array f[N][2](the first dimension is for the index of the town, the second - true or false) and use a loop to fill this array using the given formulas. It is also possible to use recursion with memoization.

Comment: hmmm i do not follow; can you please be clear. thanks in advance

Comment: how many subproblems do we have here? and what is the running time of each of them