# Dynamic programming, minimizing cost?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

I came across this question:

You have to travel through `N` blocks in a city in a car begining at block `0` and ending at block `N - 1`. Every block `i` has a gas station which provides delivery of gas at the block, from the block to `X[i]` miles to the west of the block and `Y[i]` miles to the east of the block. The gas stations serve you only when paid an initial amount `C[i]`. Assume all blocks lie on a straight road. Give an algorithm which selects the gas stations to pay such that the cash paid to the gas stations is minimized and at least one gas station delivers at every location on the road.

Things I tried:

- Brute force - Tried all possible combinations and found the best one - Worked perfectly but took too long.
- Greedy - I tried to be greedy on 1) Cost 2) Distance covered 3) cost per distance.

After ENORMOUS struggle I concluded that this is likely a Dynamic programming problem.

Attempt at Dynamic programming - I tried to come up with a recurrence with  absolutely no result, the hardest part I found was that the station delivers on both sides. To overcome that, I decided that I will "move" the stations to the west most position and increase the delivered range on the east by the same amount - couldn't continue.

I found a similar question I think, [dynamic programming proboem for minimum cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157141/dynamic-programming-proboem-for-minimum-cost)
Are these questions actually similar?

Can someone please tell me if this is *actually* a dynamic programming problem and there is no other way to do this more efficiently?
If it is a dynamic programming can you please give a few tips on how I can go about this?

### Example:

```
Suppose N is 4
block 0 : X = 1, Y = 1, C = 2
block 1 : X = 0, Y = 2, C = 1
block 2 : X = 2, Y = 2, C = 5
block 3 : X = 1, Y = 5, C = 7

Then the result will be,
Pay block 0, 1 gas stations.
Min cost : 3
```

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, it can be solved efficiently with dynamic programming. "No other way" is not well-defined.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ah ! Thank you ! Can you please give a few hints as to how I can proceed ? Help out with the recurrence please ?

Comment: @jurgemaister What sort of details can I add ?

Comment: See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @jurgemaister Will adding an example help ? (This is my first question, sorry)

Comment: @jurgemaister I added an example ! Hope that helps !

Comment: This is definitely a DP problem. This can not solved using greedy strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, we want the minimum-cost set of gas stations that will cover all blocks. This can be formulated as a shortest path problem in the following graph. Create an artificial source, an artificial sink, and a vertex for each gas station. For `i < j`, the `i`th gas station has an arc to the `j`th gas station if and only if there is no gap in their coverage. The artificial source has arcs to each gas station that covers block `0`. The artificial sink has arcs from each gas station that covers block `n-1`. The cost of each arc is the cost of the gas station at its head (`0` for the artificial sink). Find the shortest path from the source to the sink; the vertices that we visit along the way are the gas stations from which we should purchase coverage.

The running time is `O(n^2)` with the usual linear-time shortest path algorithm for acyclic directed graphs. There is probably an improvement to `O(n)`; see the [discussion on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9536). (Yuval specifies `O(n log n)` time, but that's just because he's working in a different model of computation, where sorting is `Omega(n log n)`.)

Comment: Seems to be a perfect solution !

Comment: I'll accept this after looking through it in a bit more detail ! Thank you !